# switch/case statement matlab code

Tags: matlab

```
function myFunc = executeCmdByKind(var1,kind)

switch kind
case 'open'
cmdToExecute = [''var1 '','' locationIs '',''clear''];

case 'close'
cmdToExecute = [''var1 '','' locationIs '',''delete''];

case 'move'
cmdToExecute = [''var1 '','' locationIs '',''move''];



   end
a = system(cmdToExecute);
end
```

My question is : is there a better way "optimal" to write this code as I call the same cmdToExecute only the latest arg changes

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by `latest arg changes`?

Comment: What is up with the double `''`? Is this supposed to be a cell array of strings? That is very strange Matlab syntax to me. Also you never assign to `myFunc` so your function will have no output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax makes no sense to me, but I'll stick with it. You could streamline your code like this I guess:

```
function myFunc = executeCmdByKind(var1,kind)

switch kind
case 'open'
    last = ''clear'';

case 'close'
    last = ''delete'';

case 'move'
    last = ''move'';

end

cmdToExecute = [''var1 '','' locationIs '', last];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are, as always, several ways of doing it. I'd do it like the following:

```
function myFunc = executeCmdByKind(var1,kind)
  a = {'open', 'close', 'move'};
  b = {'clear', 'delete', 'move'};
  logi = ismember(a, kind);
  cmdToExecute = [var1, locationIs, b{logi}];
```

That's not the nicest code, but it's short, if you want that ;-)
First I look via `kind` which index it has in the vector `a` and after retreiving the index, I can then select the corresponding element from `b` :-)

Edit: Short and it's easily expandable in the future with more elements :-)

Comment: The `find` should be obsolete.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sure :-) Logical indexing will also do :-)

Comment: I would add `assert(sum(logi) == 1)`

Comment: @Edric That depends on what you want to happen if kind is not in the list. Good to consider that, but perhaps it wil already work fine or perhaps you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yeah *might* be useful, but don't over-assumpt anything as the original question poster didn't give any information about it

Comment: Ok, you might prefer `assert(any(logi))` then.

Comment: It is a bit of guesswork, but the asker may be interested in this: `[var1 ' ' locationIs ' ' b{logi}]`